# Fastest/most efficient in App Engine, local file read or memcache hit?

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine

I have a couple of smaller asset files (text templates typically 100 - a few K bytes) in my app that I'm considering caching using `memcached`. But does anyone here know if loading a local file or requesting it from memcache is the fastest/most resource efficient?

(I'll be using the Python version of App Engine)

Comment: If they're templates, the templating system you're using probably already supports caching the compiled templates in memory. What library are you using?

Comment: Actually, I won't be using (server-side) templates, but static pages generated in a build script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are just few kbytes I would load them on the instance memory; amongst the storage choices (Memcache, Datastore, Blobstore and so on) on Google App Engine , ***instance memory*** option shoud be the fastest.

Comment: Um, if it takes 20-25 milliseconds to read something from instance memory (eg, a global variable), something is seriously wrong.

Comment: my bad, we are easily an order of magnitude below.(I'm getting old)